# Find positive integer $x$, $y$, $z$ such that $2x^{2x}-1=y^{z+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, online-resources

Find all positive integer $x$, $y$, $z$ such that $2x^{2x}-1=y^{z+1}$

I have tried to use LTE lemma but it didn't work.

I think my problem is $z+1$. I can not control it.

When I use LTE lemma, the purpose is proving one side is larger than another side, but I stuck in $z+1$.

Comment: x = 1, y =1, z = 1.

Comment: I think I need a detail solution

Comment: Is the question to find all solutions?  Are you aware of any others besides the (trivial) solution I proposed?

Comment: You mean $2x^{2x}$ and not $(2x)^{2x}$, right? Also, what is the significance of $z + 1$, why can't you have just $z$?

Comment: By leaving it at $z$, you allow the right-hand side to be y^z, which allows you to choose $z = 1$ and finding all values  $2x^{2x}-1=y$. The +1 makes it interesting.

Comment: Yes, it is $2.x^{2x}$ and if I replace $z+1$ by $z$ then $z=1$, we will have infinitive solution

Comment: where did you get the problem????????????

Comment: From a forum on internet.

Comment: where did they get it?